# Add foreign key relationship to existing read-only database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have an existing database that is read only and I cannot alter its structure.

The tables in this database have columns that you can use to join in SQL queries, but I want to use Entity Framework to create a model with these columns linked as if they were foreign keys.

Is there a way to create this relationship in the class structure, even if the key is not present in the actual database?

Comment: Here are some resources on custom mappings: [entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/using-entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access/), [Scott Gu's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database), [Fluent API - Configuring and Mapping Properties and Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a legacy database schema I would not recommend trying to introduce navigation properties and an artificial relationship in your EF model. If you need "related" data in one query I would probably use manual LINQ joins or stored procedures to join the data and map the loaded items into a specialized class.